# ORACLE SQL with multiple subquery

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I actually implement 2 methods in this question, one is as below, the other is using 'with' to substitute the sub queries, neither of them worked. sucks. 
this one,oracle kept showing the problem

from padoctors p right outer join
*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00936: missing expression

please help me with that

```
select distinctive *
from padoctors p right outer join
(select drug,month,max(drug_num) max_no
                from (select drug,count(*) as drug_num,to_char(prescdate,'MM') as month
                    from padoctors
                    where to_char(prescdate,'YYYY')='2012'
                    group by to_char(prescdate,'MM'),drug)
                    group by month,drug) dmax on p.drug=dmax.drug
full outer join
    (select drug,month,min(drug_num) min_no
                from (select drug,count(*) as drug_num,to_char(prescdate,'MM') as month
                    from padoctors
                    where to_char(prescdate,'YYYY')='2012'
                    group by to_char(prescdate,'MM'),drug)
                    group by month,drug) dmin on dmax.month=dmin.month and dmin.drug=p.drug
order by month asc;
```

this one, I google the usage of 'with' in http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php
Still,not working.

```
with dmax as
(
 select drug,month,max(drug_num)
 from (select drug,count(*) as drug_num,to_char(prescdate,'MM') as month
       from padoctors
       where to_char(prescdate,'YYYY')='2012'
       group by to_char(prescdate,'MM'),drug
      )
 group by month,drug
),
dmin as
(
 select drug,month,min(drug_num)
 from (select drug, count(*) as drug_num, to_char(prescdate,'MM') as month
       from padoctors
       where to_char(prescdate,'YYYY')='2012'
       group by to_char(prescdate,'MM'),drug
      )
  group by month,drug
)
select distinctive *
from dmax join dmin on dmax.month=dmin.month
order by month asc;
```

Comment: Without digging into it, it's select `DISTINCT` not dinstinctive and you need a column list for distinct `select distinct drug, month from `

Answer (score 0):

Taking what *Just Aguy* says, I played with that and yes :
`SELECT DISTINCTIVE * FROM Table` does give "**ORA-00936: missing expression**"
so you'll need `SELECT DISTINCT`